# Change background color of button in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to change the color of a button in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6.

In my _custom.scss I include:

```
$brand-primary:             $purple;
```

But to make the button change color from blue to purple I must also include:

```
$btn-primary-bg:                 $purple;
```

Shouldn't it be enough to include the first line?

This is all I have in my custom file.

```
$purple: #a02971;
$brand-primary: $purple;
$enable-rounded: false;
```

The last line successfully removes the rounded corners of my button, so I know my recompilation of the sass-files are working. But when I look in the generated css, the button background color remains the default blue.

Answer (score 6):

To get color changes to properly propagate during the scss compile, you need to edit the `bootstrap.scss` file and import custom before variables.

new `bootstrap.scss` excerpt:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "custom"; // fix problems with variable overrides not propagating
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
//@import "custom";
```

Comment: I had this same problem and this worked for me, thanks. Any idea why the imports are ordered the way that they are? (the "wrong" way)

Comment: As far as I can tell, there was an issue in alpha 5 that made them think moving the import of custom would be a good idea. It's been moved back to the "right way" for the in progress beta.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to change `$brand-primary` to set the "primary" color.

```
$purple:        #551a8b;
$brand-primary: $purple;
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/6jlKsNT416

Comment: Hi, can't include the @import statement in the _custom file. Creates an import loop.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't have to. I just included that because Codeply compiles that SASS on the fly.

Comment: Added some more information in my question. Don't know why it's not working. The remove rounded corners is working, but not the color.